# Remove Input Tensor from Squeezenet

Tags: python, tensorflow, qualcomm

I have created a Squeezenet model using [Facenet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet)
I'd like to convert my Squeezenet tensorflow model using the Qualcomm NPE. The problem is, that Qualcomm's NPE only supports a 3D tensor as an input. Squeezenet uses an image tensor plus a phase_train tensor (4D tensor) as an input. The model can be found here: [squeezenet.py](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/models/squeezenet.py)

My question is: How can I remove the phase_train tensor from the squeezenet model in order to input only an image?
Maybe one can remove the phase_train during freezing of the graph?

I think both inputs tensors are defined in line 46:

```
with tf.variable_scope('squeezenet', [images], reuse=reuse):
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.batch_norm, slim.dropout], is_training=phase_train):
```